# Какие есть плагины для infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница с контентом, необходимо частями загружать контент, чтобы получился бесконечный скролл, какой можно использовать плагин или есть какой-нибудь пример?

Answer (score 2):

Такое?

```js
let robot = 4, items_number = 2

onscroll = e => {
  const current_item = Math.round(pageYOffset / innerHeight)

  if(current_item === items_number - 1) {
    createItem(loadImage(`https://robohash.org/set=set1/${robot}`))
    items_number++; robot++
  }
}

async function loadImage(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const data =  await response.blob()
  return URL.createObjectURL(data)
}

async function createItem(x) {
  const item = document.createElement('li')
  const image = document.createElement('img')
  image.src = await x
  item.appendChild(image)
  list.appendChild(item)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  --s: calc(20vw + 20vh);
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--s);
}
```

```html
<ul id=list>
  <li>
    <img src="https://robohash.org/set=set1/0">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://robohash.org/set=set1/2">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добрый день, да, только вместо картинок к примеру блок с информацией, где будет текст, картинки и видео. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @ДмитрийМоисеев  так все тоже самое.

Comment: Только вместо пункта списка, будете создавать целый блок со всем что вам нужно